# How do I test the logger output using Test::Unit in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, logging

I adjusted the output of logs in my Rails app. I want to write a test for it using the default Rails test suite.

The problem is when you do something like:

`logger.debug "Help me debug this!"` it returns `true` and prints out to the console the message. How would I get this message and be able to test it? Once I could actually get the message, it becomes trivial string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the file and read it in ruby:

```
log_file_content = File.read('path/to/log/file')
assert_match "Help me debug this!", log_file_content
```